# Remove data in parentheses from data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, substring, character, tidyr

So I have a dataset with 49 rows and 109 features, where the data is formatted so that each entry has a mean and sd value. Here is a sample:

```
> head(score_data[,1:4])
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Variable                                                     Overall       `18 to 29`    `30 to 39`   
  <chr>                                                        <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
1 ts.tsmart_partisan_score (mean (sd))                         94.01 (9.73)  92.56 (10.82) 94.14 (9.55) 
2 ts.tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))     66.23 (24.38) 51.56 (20.02) 58.44 (24.36)
3 ts.tsmart_midterm_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))          50.29 (29.05) 31.09 (18.81) 34.82 (22.15)
4 ts.tsmart_offyear_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))          20.71 (15.08) 25.38 (17.36) 18.84 (14.35)
5 ts.tsmart_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd))     48.34 (28.12) 38.26 (22.26) 36.19 (22.72)
6 ts.tsmart_non_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd)) 40.21 (29.00) 27.03 (20.14) 23.52 (19.32)
```

I am hoping to extract just the mean value from the data, for all of the 109 columns in the dataset.  Since the features are characters, I know I could use the separate command to split out the data into two columns based on the index of the first parenthesis like so:

```
data <- data %>% separate(PrecinctName, into = c("Precinct", "PrecinctCode"), sep = 5)
```

However I would like to do this for each feature in the entire dataset, and using the method above would be time consuming, and a pain.  Does anyone have a more elegant solution?  I am not particularly concerned with keeping the sd data, so the method does not have to include that in its function.

By request, here is the alternative output:

```
    > dput( head(score_data[,1:4]))
structure(list(Variable = c("ts.tsmart_partisan_score (mean (sd))", 
"ts.tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))", "ts.tsmart_midterm_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))", 
"ts.tsmart_offyear_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))", "ts.tsmart_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd))", 
"ts.tsmart_non_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd))"
), Overall = c("94.01 (9.73)", "66.23 (24.38)", "50.29 (29.05)", 
"20.71 (15.08)", "48.34 (28.12)", "40.21 (29.00)"), `18 to 29` = c("92.56 (10.82)", 
"51.56 (20.02)", "31.09 (18.81)", "25.38 (17.36)", "38.26 (22.26)", 
"27.03 (20.14)"), `30 to 39` = c("94.14 (9.55)", "58.44 (24.36)", 
"34.82 (22.15)", "18.84 (14.35)", "36.19 (22.72)", "23.52 (19.32)"
)), .Names = c("Variable", "Overall", "18 to 29", "30 to 39"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Is your aim to separate them or delete/remove the ones in paranthesis?

Comment: @Onyambu I mean to remove the ones in the parentheses and the leading space before the parenthesis.

Comment: can you post `dput( head(score_data[,1:4]))`

Comment: Just edited post to include it.

Answer (score 1):

```
 read.table(stringsAsFactors = F,text=gsub("\\(.*?\\)|\\)","",do.call(paste,dat)))
                                                V1    V3    V4    V5
1                         ts.tsmart_partisan_score 94.01 92.56 94.14
2     ts.tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score 66.23 51.56 58.44
3          ts.tsmart_midterm_general_turnout_score 50.29 31.09 34.82
4          ts.tsmart_offyear_general_turnout_score 20.71 25.38 18.84
5     ts.tsmart_presidential_primary_turnout_score 48.34 38.26 36.19
6 ts.tsmart_non_presidential_primary_turnout_score 40.21 27.03 23.52
```

Comment: One thing you need to note is that the columns are numeric. Thus you can manipulate them the way you want

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
means <- sapply(score_data[, -1], function(x) as.numeric(substr(x, 1,
     regexpr(" ", x) - 1)))
means
#      Overall 18 to 29 30 to 39
# [1,]   94.01    92.56    94.14
# [2,]   66.23    51.56    58.44
# [3,]   50.29    31.09    34.82
# [4,]   20.71    25.38    18.84
# [5,]   48.34    38.26    36.19
# [6,]   40.21    27.03    23.52
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple regex should do this:

```
        for (i in names(score_data)[-(1)]) {   
               score_data[[i]] <- as.numeric(gsub( " .*$", "", score_data[[i]] )) 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use gsub() and regular expressions to remove any characters within the parentheses like this:

```
test <- score_data %>% mutate_at(vars(-Variable),funs(gsub("\\([^\\)]+\\)", "", ., perl = T)))


                                                    Variable Overall X18.to.29 X30.to.39
1                         ts.tsmart_partisan_score (mean (sd))  94.01     92.56     94.14 
2     ts.tsmart_presidential_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))  66.23     51.56     58.44 
3          ts.tsmart_midterm_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))  50.29     31.09     34.82 
4          ts.tsmart_offyear_general_turnout_score (mean (sd))  20.71     25.38     18.84 
5     ts.tsmart_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd))  48.34     38.26     36.19 
6 ts.tsmart_non_presidential_primary_turnout_score (mean (sd))  40.21     27.03     23.52
```